# Need to merge 2 eps files to produce output.eps in Java

Tags: graphics2d, eps

I have 2 eps files

a.eps 
 b.eps

I need to read the content of them and create a new EPS file containing both a and b. The output is made by adding a.eps and b.eps using these

1.positioning (x,y)
  2.scaling
  3.rotating

Eg. If

content of a.eps is X 
 content of b.eps is O 
 content of output.eps will X O

I am trying Graphics2D library but reading an EPS file and extracting the shape is getting challenging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is trivial, if you stick to PostScript. EPS files are 'encapsulated', that is they are totally self-contained. The intention of EPS is that you can insert an EPS file into a PostScript program directly, knowing nothing more about it than its size and shape.

All you need to do is alter the CTM between each file so that they appear in the correct position (and add the boiler plate for an EPS file round the combined file). PostScript (EPS is a subset of PostScript) has a rich set of operators for this.

So for example to combine EPS1 and EPS2, and make a new EPS from the combination, you might do:

```
%!PS-Adobe-2.0 EPSF-1.2
%%Creator:me, myself-
%%Title:combined EPS
%%CreationDate:23/5/19 9:32 AM
%%DocumentFonts:Helvetica-Bold
%%BoundingBox:0 0 612 792
%%EndComments

save
0 0 moveto
0.5 scale
...
... insert contents of EPS1 here
...
restore

save
306 0 moveto
0.5 scale
...
... insert contents of EPS1 here
...
restore

%%EOF
```

That draws EPS1 at the bottom left of the media, scaled down by 50%, then draws EPS2 at the bottom, 306 points (4.25 inches) from the left, again scaled down by 50%.

You **must** get the BoundingBox comments of the final EPS correct, this is vitally important for any application which imports the EPS.

If you really want a single EPS file, or don't want to do all the calculations and boiler plate yourself, then you could use Ghostscript's eps2write device to help. You still need to write the PostScript code to position the EPS files, but the program can be simpler. Taking the same example as above:

```
%!
save
0 0 moveto
0.5 scale
(/disk/path/EPS1.eps) run
restore
save
306 0 moveto
0.5 scale
(/disk/path/EPS2.eps) run
restore
showpage
```

Save that as a convenient file, say input.ps and then execute:

```
gs -sDEVICE=eps2write -sOutputFile=combined.eps input.ps
```

The result should be a new single EPS file containing the content of the two original EPS files with all the BoundingBox and other boilerplate taken care of for you.

Comment: I'd suggest initially (to make sure everything is working) you just press return for every page and then type quit at the GS prompt. Once you are happy that GS isn't whining about anything being wrong, run it with -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH. Then it won't pause between pages, will exit on completion and will minimise the reporting.

Comment: NB once you have the final EPS file, you can runi through Ghostscript again to see what it looks like. use -dEPSCrop-sDEVICE=png16m -sOutputFile=out.png combined.eps to get a PNG of the result.

Comment: Upon adding the parameter -dBATCH, the script started to work.------------------------>
gs -dBATCH -sDEVICE=eps2write -sOutputFile=combined.eps input.ps--------------------------- Thanks a ton Ken

Comment: From the usability point, this feature is needed in a java application running on Linux server. What java wrapper can I use for the Ghostscript and any suggestions on the installation of ghostscript in java based use case.

Comment: There's a Ghost4J (not supplied by the GS developers) at http://www.ghost4j.org. Since I know nothing at all about Java I'm unable to offer you any advice, sorry.

Comment: Thanks Ken. I will explore Ghost4J. One last question I have is, if I have to embed a.eps inside b.eps at a particular location how should I write the input.ps, The output file is b.eps itself. And thanks for all your valuable feedback, it helped me save so much time.

Comment: Ah, that you can't do trivially. EPS files are PostScript programs, you are supposed to treat them as black boxes. Because PostScript is a programming language what you are asking is how do I insert one program inside another, I'm sure you can guess how easy that is going to be :-)